# How to save and exit crontab -e?

Tags: vps, cron, centos5

How to save and exit `crontab -e`?

i tried every method listed [here](http://www.computing.net/answers/solaris/crontab-e/313.html) and none works, i have a centos 5, vi comes by default with yum and i installed nano

**Solved**

just changed the default editor

```
export EDITOR=nano
```

and now i can do what I do using nano :) thanks everyone and yes i should learn Vi.. someday!!!

Comment: `echo $EDITOR`?

Comment: @quanta sir didn't work well maybe I'm doing something wrong since I'm used to use nano and not vi ok so I open contab -e, write echo $EDITOR and press enter, it does not exit, it goes down 1 line

Comment: No, I mean type `echo $EDITOR` from the terminal to determine what default editor you are using.

Comment: @quanta thank you for reminding me that i can change my default editor :D

Comment: for users coming here;
apparently the default editor is decided in /usr/bin/sensible-editor and on my installation it decided on the editor called '[ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor))' as default. Ed can be exited by typing 'q' followed by 'Enter'.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the first thing is to make sure you're using an editor you like.

We're all admins here, so we all like `vi` (ducks, runs).

```
export VISUAL=vi
crontab -e
```

(do some edits, finishing with ESCAPE)

```
:wq
```

And `crontab -l` should now show you your new crontab.  If you prefer some other editor, set that in the VISUAL environment variable, and exit it as appropriate.

Comment: sir, I'm not used to vi, i use nano, that's why I'm having difficulties :)

Comment: I'm glad you've found a solution; but may I encourage you to ask the question you want answered in future?  Perhaps a better question here would have been "how do I change the editor that's invoked when I type `crontab -e`"?  People will be quick enough to offer alternatives if the thing you actually want seems impossible.

Comment: You can also hit `ESC` then `:x` to save and exit, or hit `ESC` then `ZZ` (that's `shift`+`zz`).

Comment: sorry :D when I asked the question i wanted to figure out how to do it in vi and then quanta asked me to see what is my default editor, then i remembered to change it and do it easily with nano - I did not have that idea when i asked the question :D

Answer (score 8):

To **exit vi** editor:

Usually the new or modified file is saved when you leave vi. However, it is also possible to quit vi without saving the file. The cursor moves to bottom of screen whenever a colon (:) is typed.

```
:x<Enter>   quit vi, writing out modified file to file named in original invocation
:wq<Enter>  quit vi, writing out modified file to file named in original invocation
:q<Enter>   quit (or exit) vi
:q!<Enter>  quit vi even though latest changes have not been saved for this vi call
```

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, answer by pressing <kbd>y</kbd> to save changes and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

`esc`-`esc`-`:wq`? Are you saying vi is the default editor, and you want nano instead?

Saving and quitting vi is outlined here:
http://www.helpdesk.umd.edu/documents/4/4793/#a13

Answer (score 1):

If your crontab -e is runned in the joe-editor, try:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to exit without saving changes

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to save and exit